# How to test if cmd.exe command exists?

Tags: batch-file, dos, cmd

As example, on Windows 7 `mklink` is available from `cmd.exe /C mklink` however on Windows XP it is not.

Apart from executing `cmd.exe /C mklink` and trying to read the `errorlevel` is there a simpler way to test if cmd.exe supports a command?

Thanks!

Comment: mklink isn't "supported" by cmd.exe, it's a program itself so you can check if it exists in the System32 directory (bad) or check the Windows version (better).

Comment: It's a program itself?  That contradicts a lot of what the internet says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ERRORLEVEL` of `cmd` is not a good indicator for command existence, as it is set to a non-zero value if either the command does not exist or if it fails, and this can throw your test off.

Alternatively, you can do one of the following:

#### Check the OS version

Like Adriano suggested in a comment, it is possible to check for the version of Windows like so:

```
set mklink_supported=true
ver | find "XP" >nul 2>&1 && set mklink_supported=false
```

or like so:

```
set mklink_supported=false
echo %vers% | find "Windows 7" >nul 2>&1 && set mklink_supported=true
```

and then:

```
if %mklink_supported%==false (
    echo 'mklink' is not supported on this operating system.
)
```

or something along these lines. You need to make sure that you're handling all the necessary OS versions, though.

#### Testrun the command and check `ERRORLEVEL`

Alternatively, you can attempt to run `mklink` directly. If it is not found, `ERRORLEVEL` is set to `9009`:

```
@echo off
mklink >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 9009 if not errorlevel 9010 (
    echo 'mklink' is not supported on this operating system.
)
```

Please note that there are two `if`-statements. `if errorlevel 9009` works if `ERRORLEVEL`>=9009, so the second `if`-statement is needed to rule out the case when `ERRORLEVEL`>9009).

I prefer the second solution as it is expected to work on all versions of Windows.

Comment: Version checking seems to be the solution that fits best for my case.

Answer (score 1):

To locate an executable you could use variable expansion in a `for` loop:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set found=no
for %%f in (mklink.exe) do if exist "%%~$PATH:f" set found=yes
echo %found%
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off 
(for /f %%F in ('help') do echo '%%F ')|findstr /i /c:"%1 " 2>&1 >nul && echo Supported || echo Not supported
```

This hinges on a fact that `help` *seems to include* pretty complete list of internal commands (and quite a few of external ones). 
It expects command name as it's argument (`isSupported.bat command_name`)

It does not actually test if a given command executes, only if it's supposed to be there...
It's just an idea, please **do try** to invalidate it and I will happily delete if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this [batch script on the SS64 Windows CMD Shell forum](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1479) a while ago. It combines the ideas found in the wmz and Ansgar Wiechers answers into one convenient package.

It attempts to locate a given executable somewhere in the PATH, and then searches HELP if not found. It can give erroneous results with some ugly error messages if a standard utility covered by HELP is missing.

```
::WHICH.BAT  CommandName  [ReturnVar]
::
::  Determines the full path of the file that would execute if
::  CommandName were executed.
::
::  The result is stored in variable ReturnVar, or else it is
::  echoed to stdout if ReturnVar is not specified.
::
::  If no file is found, then an error message is echoed to stderr.
::
::  The ERRORLEVEL is set to one of the following values
::    0 - Success: A matching file was found
::    1 - No file was found and CommandName is an internal command
::    2 - No file was found and CommandName is not an internal command
::    3 - Improper syntax - no CommandName specified
::
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file=%~1"
if not defined file (
  >&2 echo Syntax error: No CommandName specified
  exit /b 3
)
set "noExt="
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%~x1" neq "" if "!PATHEXT:%~x1=!" neq "!PATHEXT!" set noExt="";
set "modpath=.\;!PATH!"
@for %%E in (%noExt%%PATHEXT%) do @for %%F in ("!file!%%~E") do (
  setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  if not "%%~$modpath:F"=="" if not exist "%%~$modpath:F\" (
    endlocal & endlocal & endlocal
    if "%~2"=="" (echo %%~$modpath:F) else set "%~2=%%~$modpath:F"
    exit /b 0
  )
  endlocal
)
endlocal
>nul help %~1 && (
  >&2 echo "%~1" is not a valid command
  exit /b 2
)
>&2 echo "%~1" is an internal command
```

Comment: why you us **3** endlocal in for loop ? endlocal & endlocal & endlocal

Comment: @user1726251 - Parts of the algorithm require delayed expansion, but FOR variable expansion is corrupted if value contains `!` while delayed expansion is enabled, and `!` is legal in path names. Multiple FOR statements are used, so I strategically use multiple SETLOCAL to get the correct delayed expansion state as needed, and at the end I require multiple ENDLOCAL to balance.